# PHP undefined-index when getting information from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm currently getting `undefined-index` with the following line in my view

`<?php echo $contentMangement['cms_name']; ?>`

I am getting the information fine from the DB

[image]

Can someone explain why I am getting this error?

Comment: The screenshot isn't clear about what is being dumped, is that $contentManagement? Maybe you need  $contentManagement[0]->cms_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the index is `0`. And then the attribute off *that* is `cms_name`.

```
$contentManagement[0]->cms_name
```

Answer (score 1):

seems that you are dealing with an array of objects. Try:

```
<?php echo $contentMangement[0]->cms_name; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe this could help :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calculating the size of the array first, before explicitly retrieving an array's value with that index

Answer (score 0):

`$contentManagement` looks like it's an array of objects. Objects don't use bracket notation (`[]`), but rather arrow notation (`->`).

So first, you'll have to get the element of the one-item array:

```
$object = $contentManagement[0];
```

And then you can access the `cms_name` property of that object:

```
$value = $object->cms_name;
```